# Is there a way to get notifications about windows console oput

Tags: winapi, console

I know I can read console buffer using ReadConsoleOutput function.
Is there any way to be notified when console app is outputing text ? Currently I need to set timer and scan the console buffer all the time.

Ty.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure I totally understand what you're trying to do - would this help?

```
Process process = new Process();

process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.OutputDataReceived += 
    new DataReceivedEventHandler(HandleConsoleOutput);

process.Start( );
```

and then handle all output being written to the console output by that process using this handler:

```
void HandleConsoleOutput(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  // Std output arrives here
}
```

Marc

Comment: Notice the WINAPI tag :) 
Thanx for the sample anyway, it made me remember I have somewhere similar api code...